# No me dejan entrar en la pagina de Laravel

Tags: laravel

Veran, ahora resulta que consigo entrar en la pagina de laravel y me piden que cree un usuario, con su nombre y contraseña.
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Creo mi cuenta de usuario y intento hacer login, pero me sale esto.
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

¿Como lo arreglo?

Por cierto, esto son los datos del fichero env:

```
APP_NAME=Laravel
APP_ENV=local
APP_KEY=base64:Tku47SsmOzOPUH206Lk6xgWpCeXUtNuBBQarsFT0kos=
APP_DEBUG=true
APP_LOG_LEVEL=debug
APP_URL=http://localhost

DB_CONNECTION=mysql
DB_HOST=127.0.0.1
DB_PORT=3306
DB_DATABASE=persona
DB_USERNAME=root
DB_PASSWORD=

BROADCAST_DRIVER=log
CACHE_DRIVER=file
SESSION_DRIVER=file
SESSION_LIFETIME=120
QUEUE_DRIVER=sync

REDIS_HOST=127.0.0.1
REDIS_PASSWORD=null
REDIS_PORT=6379

MAIL_DRIVER=smtp
MAIL_HOST=smtp.mailtrap.io
MAIL_PORT=2525
MAIL_USERNAME=null
MAIL_PASSWORD=null
MAIL_ENCRYPTION=null

PUSHER_APP_ID=
PUSHER_APP_KEY=
PUSHER_APP_SECRET=
PUSHER_APP_CLUSTER=mt1
```

Otra cosa, ahora me encuentro conque se perdio mi cuenta, pero al volver a hacerla, me sale esto:[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Parece que ya me admiten, pero no pasa por ahora nada en especial. Creo que tiene que conectarse con una base phpmyadmin y mostrarse los datos de una tabla.

Comment: ¿La base de datos esta corriendo? y ¿Los datos de conexión de la app a la BD son correctos?

Comment: ¿Está correcta sus datos de conexión a la bd en el archivo .env ?

Comment: @Dev.Joel he incluido más información sobre ese archivo.

Comment: @MiguelAlparez tenga en cuenta el primer comentario de Julian , está corriendo su servidor MySQL? ¿No tiene clave el usuario root?

Comment: @Dev.Joel He activado Apache y MySQL en XAMPP. Y en CMD he activado php artisan serve. ¿Algo más?

Comment: Y cierto, mi usuario es root. Carezco de contraseña.

Comment: Tengo otra edición...